# Submit Form does not generate clean url in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms, url-routing

I have a search form and I want to generate a clean Url when the Form is submitted.

I have created a custom Route for this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Custom",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{KEY}/{BN}/{SBN}/{CN}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
            );
```

This is my form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("TestUrl", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
{
    <input type="text" name="KEY" value="q"/>
    <input type="text" name="BN" value="Miscellaneous" />
    <input type="text" name="SBN" value="Specialized Photographic Equipment" />
    <input type="text" name="CN" value="South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands" />
<input type="submit" value="Search"/>
}
```

My Action is as follows:

```
 public ActionResult TestUrl(string KEY,string BN,string SBN, string CN)
        {
            return View();
        }
```

When I submit the form, it generates a url like this:

> http://localhost:59548/Home/TestUrl?KEY=q&BN=Miscellaneous&SBN=Specialized+Photographic+Equipment&CN=South+Georgia+and+the+South+Sandwich+Islands

Where as my `ActionLink` is generating a clean url:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Test Link", "TestUrl", "Home", new { KEY = "0", BN = "Miscellaneous", SBN = "Specialized Photographic Equipment", CN = "South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands" }, new { })
```

The `ActionLink` will generate this clean Url:

> http://localhost:59548/Home/TestUrl/0/Miscellaneous/Specialized%20Photographic%20Equipment/South%20Georgia%20and%20the%20South%20Sandwich%20Islands

How can I remove the query string when I submit form?

Comment: did you try with POST?

Comment: @shanavascet: if I'll make it `POST` Then It won't generate URL like what I want .

Comment: with get you are bound to get the querystring.

Comment: if your data contains space it will be replaced with %20 and all when you use GET method

Comment: @maz3tt: URL Routing won't help me ?

Comment: @shanavascet: %20 is no problem. But I want all the input value is seprated by `/` not by querystring.

Comment: the client browser (where the form submit happens) has no concept of your routing, so will use the querystring. You can, potentially, intercept the click event with JS, read the form and send the user to the page with the pretty url.

Comment: The difference is that your `ActionLink()` is adding route parameters and the razor code checks your route definitions, where as the browser constructs the url when submitting a form.

Comment: `form method="get"` is an html feature that is agnostic of your serverside "nice" routes. You can only get  `{controller}/{action}/{KEY}/{BN}/{SBN}/{CN}` with javascript

Answer (score 1):

What you're missing is including your route variables within the setup. It's not just enough to have them as a part of your route, but also within the anonymous object.

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Custom",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{KEY}/{BN}/{SBN}/{CN}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index",
                KEY = "", BN = "", SBN = "", CN = "" }
        );
```

Comment: Still It is creating query string

Comment: The other option you have would be to dynamically alter the form's url in JavaScript.

Comment: The problem that you're having is that you're trying to force the HTTP method into a GET, when what you're doing is a POST. When you take user input and send it to the server, you need to **post** that data. When you know exactly what item you're asking for, you are performing a **get**. If you make this a static link, you are fine with a GET, but if you're giving the user options to choose, then you need to POST.